Converting \zposx and \zposy Coordinates to Points (pt)
I need to store the position of Image's x & y position which present inside figure environment.
I am getting the value as 8799518, 47171296 which I need to convert as pt.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=coords.txt

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storexypos}[2][1]{%
   \zsavepos{#1}%
   \immediate\write\mywrite{#1: \zposx{#1}, \zposy{#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\storexypos[fig-f1]{Figure Location}
\centering{\fbox{\vbox to 5pc{\vfil\hbox to 10pc{\hss\vbox{\hbox{FPO}}\hss}\vfil}}}%
\caption{Text for testing}\label{fig01}
\end{figure}

\immediate\closeout\mywrite

\end{document}

Present output:
coords.txt
fig-f1: 8799518, 47171296

Requested output:
coords.txt
fig-f1: 134.29pt, 719.88pt


they are values in sp units which you can use directly or if you really need pt just divide by 65536 (2^16)

You could use \dim_eval:n {... sp} to convert from small points to pt:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=coords.txt

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\storexypos}[2][1]{%
   \zsavepos{#1}%
   \immediate\write\mywrite{#1:~\dim_eval:n {\zposx{#1} sp}, ~\dim_eval:n {\zposy{#1} sp}}{}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\storexypos[fig-f1]{Figure Location}
\centering{\fbox{\vbox to 5pc{\vfil\hbox to 10pc{\hss\vbox{\hbox{FPO}}\hss}\vfil}}}%
\caption{Text for testing}\label{fig01}
\end{figure}

\immediate\closeout\mywrite

\end{document}

